# Character encoding issue MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to store strings that contains special characters with MySQL (PHP with PDO).

I've created a UTF-8 php project in netbeans and utf8_general_ci tables in MySQL. The page header contains `<meta charset="UTF-8">` already.

When i store the word 'Acentuação', it appears to me as 'AcentuaÃ§Ã£o' (tried w/ phpmyadmin 4.1.14 and Heidisql 9.1 - http://www.heidisql.com/)

Im missing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Thank you @Mihai . I was missing the connection char-encoding: `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8mb4');`